# React data state from server render only 3 data and 1 duplicate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my code

```
 export default class Product extends Component {

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
    const { params } = nextProps.navigation.state;
    const getCategoryId = params ? params.categoryId : 7;
    const getCategoryIndex = params ? params.categoryIndex : 0;
    return {
      categoryId: getCategoryId,
      categoryIndex: getCategoryIndex,
    };
  }

  state = {
    loadCategoryTab: { data: [] },
    loadProduct: {},
    storeExistId: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() { this.onLoadCategory(); }
  onLoadCategory = () => {
    axios.get(CATEGORY_API)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          loadCategoryTab: res.data,
        });
        setTimeout(() => { this.tabIndex.goToPage(this.state.categoryIndex); });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
  onScrollChange = () => {
    const targetId = this.tabClick.props.id;
    if (this.state.storeExistId.indexOf(targetId) === -1) {
      this.loadProductItem(targetId);
    } else {
      this.setState({ categoryId: targetId });
    }
  }
  loadProductItem = (id) => {
    axios.get(`${PRODUCT_API}/${this.state.categoryId}`)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          const newProductObj = { ...prevState.loadProduct, [id]: res.data };
          const newStoreObj = prevState.storeExistId.concat(id);
          return {
            categoryId: id,
            loadProduct: newProductObj,
            storeExistId: newStoreObj,
          };
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
  render() {
    const { loadCategoryTab, loadProduct, categoryId } = this.state;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Tabs
          // NB 2.3.9 not fixyet need to use `ref` to replace `initialPage`
          ref={(component) => { this.tabIndex = component; }}
          // initialPage={categoryIndex}
          renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab />}
          onChangeTab={this.onScrollChange}
          tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ }}
          style={{}}
        >
          {
            loadCategoryTab.data.length > 0 &&
            loadCategoryTab.data.map((item) => {
              const { id, name } = item;
              return (
                <Tab
                  key={id}
                  id={id}
                  ref={(tabClick) => { this.tabClick = tabClick; }}
                  heading={name}
                  tabStyle={{ backgroundColor: Color.darkBlue }}
                  activeTabStyle={{ backgroundColor: Color.darkBlue }}
                >
                  <View>
                    {
                      Object.keys(loadProduct).length > 0 &&
                      loadProduct[categoryId].data.map((subItem) => {
                        return (<Text key={id}>{categoryId}| {subItem.prod_name}</Text>);
                      })
                    }
                  </View>
                </Tab>
              );
            })
          }
        </Tabs>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

this is my expected object

```
{
  "1": {
    data: [{etc.....}]
  },
  "2": {
    data: [{etc.....}]
  },
}
```

i'm out of idea how to mutate new state it work but it missing 1 piece like

```
Tab 1: = product key 1
Tab 2: = product key 1
Tab 3: = product key 2
Tab 4: = product key 3
```

but if i console my categoryId it work as i excepted

```
 Tab 1: = categoryId  1
 Tab 2: = categoryId  2
 Tab 3: = categoryId  3
 Tab 4: = categoryId  4
```

- First i Click Button to go to my Product page and init Category from
  server to create Tab scollable because Nativebase Tabs bug with
  initialPage so need ref and manually trigger Tab for first load only
  and after Tab will listen to onChange event when i do swap or click
  on tab.
- every time Tab is click or swap it will check my condition
  storeExistId with categoryId from React navigation prams if not exist
  it will call loadProductItem but if exist i set categoryId to new id
  from categoryId from params.
- so my loadProductItem() not fire everytime i swap or click tab it
  need check condition first.
  loadProduct will store all product that has been load i do this to prevent axios fire everytime i do action.
  but it not as i excepted 4 data only 3 data is render and has 1 duplicate.i have use prevState it still same.
  Please Help.

  ### Thank in advanced

Update i found my problem with this.state.categoryId is late to pass new id to my Request so data is dulplicate for 2nd time.

> loadProductItem = (id) => {
>       axios.get(`${PRODUCT_API}/${this.state.id}`)'

to

> loadProductItem = (id) => {
>       axios.get(`${PRODUCT_API}/${id}`)

Answer (score 0):

In this piece of code:

```
loadProduct[categoryId].data.map((subItem) => {
    return (<Text key={id}>{categoryId}| {subItem.prod_name}</Text>);
})
```

You are using `id`, which will come not from this `map`, but from the parent

`loadCategoryTab.data.map((item) => {
   const { id, name } = item;`

So in the categoryId loop, you will place multiple items with the same `key`. This is not good.

Comment: yes i stuck this problem for 3 day so my code start look messy and my subItem.prod_id become id hahaha. i fixed my own problem will edit answer after this. Thank :D